# Why do I need to also share the encryption key with the other account when sharing an encrypted snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

In the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modifying-snapshot-permissions.html) it says that

> When you share an encrypted snapshot, you **must also share the customer**
> **managed key used to encrypt the snapshot**.

but why is that necessary? Why does the receiving account need the encryption key when I share with it an encrypted snapshot? To make use of the snapshot, they should only need the decryption key, right?

Comment: What is that thing you call "decryption key" and where would you get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the use of Symmetric-key algorithms to encrypt/decrypt data. Symmetric encryption is a type of encryption where only one key (a secret key) is used to both encrypt and decrypt electronic data hence its why you must share it.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that the encryption algorithm used was symmetric.